# Nilpotent element in Ring of continuous function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, continuity

Let $C[0,1]$ denote the ring of continuous function on compact set $[0,1]$.

**I have already checked that this ring is not an integral domain.**

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if}\;\;\;0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}\\2x-1&\text{if}\;\;\;\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$$

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}-2x+1&\text{if}\;\;\;0\leq x<\frac{1}{2}\\0&\text{if}\;\;\;\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$$

*Lemma: We can show that if $R $ is an integral domain then $0 $ is the only nilpotent element in the ring.*

Proof: Let $a\in R, a\neq 0$ and suppose $a^n=0$ for some $n>1$

$$a^n=aa^{n-1}=0$$ which imply that $a=0$ as $R$ is integral domain.

**Main Question**

Since $R=C[0,1]$ is not an integral domain, should I expect some nilpotent elements. I am not able to construct such element.

May be I am wrong and this ring work as an counterexample to the converse of the above lemma.

Comment: Another example of a non-integral domain lacking nilpotents is $\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no nilpotent elements (save the zero element): $C[0,1]$ is a *reduced* ring.

The proof is immediate: if $f\in C[0,1]$ and $f^n=0$, then $f(x)^n=0$
for all $x\in[0,1]$, so that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.